# Column value equals list item, if item is substring in one of multiple columns

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

Using PowerQuery I want to create a new column, with a value equal to an item from a list {MED_NAME_LIST}, if that item is a substring in one of multiple columns: [Name], [GenericName], [SimpleGenericName].

In a previous post I asked about how to filter based on whether multiple text columns ([Name], [GenericName], or [SimpleGenericName]) contains a substring from a list.

[Powerquery, does string contain an item in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62355524/powerquery-does-string-contain-an-item-in-a-list)

The solution worked well, but now i realized I need to also know what the matching list item is.

Previous solution to filter based on a list:

````
    MED_NAME_LIST = {"MEthYlprednisolone", "hYdroxychloroquine", "rEMdesivir"},
    initialTable = Table.FromRows({
        {"Methylprednisolone Tab", "train", "car", "bike"},
        {"no", "no", "no", "no"},
        {"tram", "teleport", "hydroxychloroQuine Tab", "jet"},
        {"no", "no", "no", "yes"},
        {"REMdesivir Tab", "bus", "taxi", "concord"}
    }, type table [Name = text, GenericName = text, SimpleGenericName = text, SomeOtherColumn = text]),
    filtered = Table.SelectRows(initialTable, each List.ContainsAny(
        {[Name], [GenericName], [SimpleGenericName]},
        MED_NAME_LIST,
        (rowValue as text, medicineFromList as text) as logical => Text.Contains(rowValue, medicineFromList, Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    ))
in
    filtered```
````

Answer (score 0):

Custom would be the last match.

Custom.1 would be a list of all the matches, if there are more than one

```
let MED_NAME_LIST = {"MEthYlprednisolone", "hYdroxychloroquine", "rEMdesivir"},
initialTable = Table.FromRows({
    {"Methylprednisolone Tab", "train", "car", "bike"},
    {"no", "no", "no", "no"},
    {"tram", "teleport", "hydroxychloroQuine Tab", "jet"},
    {"no", "no", "no", "yes"},
    {"REMdesivir Tab", "bus", "taxi", "concord"}
}, type table [Name = text, GenericName = text, SimpleGenericName = text, SomeOtherColumn = text]),
filtered = Table.SelectRows(initialTable, each List.ContainsAny(
    {[Name], [GenericName], [SimpleGenericName]},
    MED_NAME_LIST,
    (rowValue as text, medicineFromList as text) as logical => Text.Contains(rowValue, medicineFromList, Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
)),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(filtered, "Custom", each List.Accumulate(List.Transform(MED_NAME_LIST, each Text.Lower(_)), null, (state, current) => if Text.Contains(Text.Lower([Name]&[GenericName]&[SimpleGenericName]), current) then current else state)),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom.1", each List.Accumulate(List.Transform(MED_NAME_LIST, each Text.Lower(_)), {}, (state, current) => if Text.Contains(Text.Lower([Name]&[GenericName]&[SimpleGenericName]), current) then List.Combine({{current}, state}) else state))
in #"Added Custom1"
```